# UTF8 characters in windows 10 file explorer not displaying correctly

Tags: windows-explorer, unicode, filenames, utf-8

I have a Dropbox folder which I sync between Linux and Windows 10. If I create a file with a special character like `ä` on Windows it is encoded as UTF16 and displays correctly on Linux. If I create a file with the same character on Linux it is encoded as UTF8 and does not display correctly in the file explorer on windows, but instead as `Ã¤`.

Can I somehow get Windows file explorer to correctly display UTF8 characters in filenames?

Comment: Are your Linux locale settings correct? That is, does Dropbox _know_ it is running on a system with `foo_BAR.UTF-8` locale and not the default ASCII one?

Comment: This is a windows problem if the file is shown correctly on Linux.